# How Select unique element from same inputs fields

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Please find below HTML of both selected input field but I need to select the first one and please find below my XPath - please help me thanks in advance

```
//*[contains(@id,'CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR') and 
    contains(@parentquestion,"|_VISA")]
```

**First input**

```
<input value="" class="form-control flleft fln masked" defaultvalue="" 
 id="CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR!_9beb0a0e-e089-4d9b-a7c3-75e69f40484c" 
 onclick="showChildQuestions(this);" 
 parentquestion="CC_CARD_TYPE_!SEPARATOR!_4185c1bd-b262-431e-a05d-c174f926a8bf_|_VISA" 
 questionid="CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR!_9beb0a0e-e089-4d9b-a7c3-75e69f40484c" 
 type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="16" 
 style="-webkit-text-security: disc;">
```

**Second input**

```
<input value="" class="form-control flleft fln masked" defaultvalue="" 
 id="CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR!_3c59ab5f-a770-454a-8ee6-d76fc32a9dea" 
 onclick="showChildQuestions(this);" 
 parentquestion="CC_CARD_TYPE_!SEPARATOR!_e245a7f5-d623-4a79-ad42-e2ec6c8c0dbf_|_VISA" 
 questionid="CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR!_3c59ab5f-a770-454a-8ee6-d76fc32a9dea" 
 type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="16" 
 style="-webkit-text-security: disc;">
```

Comment: Both the `<input>` tags being identical, to construct a unique locator you need to update the question with parent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath with index:

```
(//*[contains(@id,'CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR') and contains(@parentquestion,"|_VISA")])[1]
(//*[contains(@id,'CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR') and contains(@parentquestion,"|_VISA")])[2]
```

Or you can do it with Selenium:

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'CC_CARD_NUMBER_!SEPARATOR') and contains(@parentquestion,"|_VISA")]"));
inputs.get(0).click();
inputs.get(1).click();
```

Or you can use reference element in html.